# jQuery css : put a variable in the "top" property

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to tell the distance from the top of the window and change the css with jQuery if the user makes scroll. I tried things like this and doesn't work:

```
var topDistance = $('div').offset().top; // distance of the div relative to the top of the window
$('div').css({position: 'absolute',top:topDistance, right:'0px'});
```

Is there a way to put the variable in the "top" property of the jQuery css ? I tried the code above and It does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to  improve the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the value of the offset from the top of the webpage. I use this for scrolling menus (which follow the user as they scroll down the page).

To change the CSS you need to use the [`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event on the window. Here is the code I use for moving an element (e.g. menu) down the page as a user scrolls. Hopefully this will help you:

```
var scrollTimer;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // this will set a callback on the scroll event for the window
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        // i'm using a timer so that the menu "catches up" once the user has scrolled and finished scrolling
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
        scrollTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            scrollSidebar();
        }, 200);
    });
});

// this function will animate the object down
function scrollSidebar(){
    // get the scroll location of the body 
    var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();

    // offset of the menu I want to follow as you scroll
    var offset = $('#scroll-menu').offset();

    // get the margin-top to see if its already scrolled down at all
    var margintop = $('#scroll-menu').css('margin-top');

    // this just checks if the user has scrolled down so the top of the menu element is now off the screen (e.g. if they have scrolled too far then the menu should follow the scroll amount, if the top of the element is in view then it needs to revert to the top again)
    if(scrollTop > (offset.top-parseInt(margintop))){
        $('#scroll-menu').animate({'margin-top':(scrollTop-(offset.top-parseInt(margintop)))+'px'}, "fast"); // 20 px extra padding
    }
    else {
        $('#scroll-menu').animate({'margin-top':'0px'});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer but it is too difficult for me. I don't understand it very well. I tried to simplify it here with a practical example: http://jsfiddle.net/ATPdt/ Perhaps someone could solve it from here, but please in a vey simple way!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ATPdt/1/ You should read the comments in my code. I just copied and pasted my code into your jsfiddle and changed the selectors from `#scroll-menu` to `#right`.

Comment: Oh, the reason why yours wasn't working was because there was no callback on the window's scroll event. i.e. your code wasn't getting called every time you scrolled the page. It was getting called once - when the page loaded and that is it. If you don't understand what I just said, you should really look up about jQuery, callbacks, events and such a bit more before you start trying to doing complicated stuff like this.